# How can I solve "No projects support the 'serve' target." Error?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to run ng serve in the command line in VSCode tihs error pops out:
"No projects support the 'serve' target."
 What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

run npm install --ignore-scripts
from the project directory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Update @angular/cli

1. npm install -g @angular/cli
2. npm install @angular/cli
3. ng update @angular/cli

see also this link :
http://cssstars.com/no-projects-support-the-serve-target/

Comment: I didn't quite understand where I can find angular cli path in my system. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check angular.json file, must be something is not proper with the projects property